# gzip a file in Python (cloud function)

Tags: python, gzip

i think i'm going crazy. I am trying to compress a css file. in (gzip) .gz.

So far all is well. when i gzip it from my terminal i have no loss in compression and decompression on the other hand when i use my python code or the system call i have a loss of info in the file. File is truncated/ missing Code i can see the end of file. I 'am under mac os.

i used 2 code below same result.

```
 def gzip_blob(self,blob_name):
    path = "/tmp"
    path_file=path+"/"+blob_name
    path_gzip_file=path+"/"+blob_name+".gz"
    with open(path_file, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(path_gzip_file, 'wb',compresslevel=self.compresslevel) as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(f_in)
    os.remove(path_file) 
    os.rename(path_gzip_file, path_file)

def gzip_file(self,blob_name):
    path = "/tmp"
    path_file=path+"/"+blob_name
    print("Zip file:"+path_file)
    # path_gzip_file=path+"/"+blob_name+".gz"
    cmd = "gzip -c /tmp/sphere.css > /tmp/sphere-css.gz"
    os.system(cmd) 
    print("gzip done")
```

Did i miss something ?

when i do an gzip in my term it's work :

gzip -c /tmp/sphere.css > /tmp/sphere-css.gz
no lost of information
gzip -d  /tmp/sphere-css.gz

I don't understand my mistake

1. with my terminal

JULIEN  wheel  117145 16 mar 21:20 sphere.css. ==> OK with terminal

2. with python Code

JULIEN  wheel  114688 16 mar 21:20 sphere-css. ==> KO  missing info  with python code

maybe i forget something

Comment: Which python version are you using? Can you share the gzipped and original file?

Comment: `f_out.writelines(f_in)` is wrong when dealing with binary files (and can allocate up to ~8x the memory of the file size); it should be `shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)` instead (with constant memory allocation). I had the written as an answer, but was unable to craft an input file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: hello @phihag you can find the assets here : https://assets.decathlon.site/4229bcd0bffda215be655d77d04466b7/sphere.css

normaly when you compress an decompresse with gzip you will end with at the end : {flex-flow:column}}

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: For me this works fine. Just to be able to reproduce it, I added a repository here: https://github.com/phihag/so-gzip-problem . @brunetjulien If you run `./demonstrate.sh` in this repository, can you reproduce the problem? If so, what is your Python version? If that repo does not reproduce your problem, can you tell me the difference between its code and yours? (e.g. compresslevel, method of decompression)

Comment: Hello @philag i found the bug , the bug was in dowloading file . the Gzip function is correct in fact .There is a bug with libs google sdk